# Split a row into two for attendance set

Tags: sql-server, unpivot

I'm redesigning an attendance system used in my company. Originally, an attendance sheet was rendered on a grid that was getting week-by-week data pivoted. I've opted for a *scheduler* control by DevExpress. A sign-in and a sign-out are to be represented as two 'appointments' now.

The scheduler requires a very specific data source for appointments. Here is my attendance table:

[image: Attendace System Backend]

The DutyIn_Manual is what the employee reports and the DutyIn is the actual time captured. DutyIn_Manual is to be shown on the Scheduler. Similarly, DutyOut_Manual goes into view.

Now, I need to split one row into two: One for Duty In and one for Duty Out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [Table Value Constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd776382.aspx) in a cross apply to generate two rows for each row in the source table.

```
declare  @T table
(
  ID int identity primary key,
  DutyIn datetime,
  DutyOut datetime,
  DutyInManual datetime,
  DutyOutManual datetime
);


insert into @T values 
('2016-10-01T10:10:00', '2016-10-01T10:50:00', '2016-10-01T10:00:00', '2016-10-01T11:00:00');

select T.ID,
       S.DutyAuto,
       S.DutyManual
from @T as T
  cross apply (values(T.DutyIn, T.DutyInManual),
                     (T.DutyOut, T.DutyOutManual)) as S(DutyAuto, DutyManual);
```